# How can you do a silent reinstallation of java?

Tags: java

I have a requirement where I need to reinstall the same version of JRE if the previous attempt of installation corrupts the JRE. corruption here means the missing of some binaries or mismatch of binaries from previous versions.

Can someone tell if there is any method to silently reinstall the jre?

I know that interactively we can reinstall the jre, where before reinstalling it shows the dialog to user for his approval. if he chooses to go ahead it succeeds. but through command line how to achieve it?

Comment: What context are you considering here?  Is the user knowingly running an installer for a bespoke application?  Are you trying to automate an update to desktop PCs as a sysadmin?  Are you trying to install the JRE for visitors to a website?

Comment: we are trying to install jre to get our work done. but if the jre is not installed successfully. we retry the installation. while this retry we are finding problem. as in the official site of Java there is no documentation is available for repair or something like that. Here I am specific to silent mode only. I know interactively we can do the repair.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest UAC(User Access Control) in windows it is impossible to install anything with escalating user permissions (to write something in Program Files) folder. So complete silence in installation is impossible.

If by silent you mean that user interacts only with UAC and nothing else, then you should look at the command line options for the setup file, by executing setup.exe /? on windows

Answer (score 0):

After lot of searches I have found that silent repair or reinstall operation is not supported by jre. Still if we want to go with it we need to use the jre_x.x_x.msi which is extracted to the location C:\Users\\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\jre1.6.0_20_x64. I am not sure it will work always. but if you are lucky it may work out.